# surround sound channels missing when using Windows Audio

Tags: windows-10, audio, surround-sound

I have a 7.1 headset which works via USB (Logitech G633) connected to a laptop running Windows 10 64-bit. I don't know when exactly, but some time ago the surround sound stopped working properly (maybe a Windows Update?). The device is still registered as a 7.1 audio output device in windows, but when configuring I can only hear the test sounds for the front left and front right channel. I have the same effect when using the surround sound configuration in the Logitech driver software.

In my search for a solution, I found [this test file](http://www.logitech.com/pub/techsupport/gaming/7.1auditionOutLeaderv2.zip). When playing it with the Windows Media Player, it's the same as before. But playing it with Media Player Classic (shipped with the [CCCP](http://www.cccp-project.net/)) I can hear all channels, so I'm sure it's not a hardware problem.

I already contacted the Logitech support, but didn't receive anything besides the automatic response to opening the ticket. Has anybody an idea how I can make it work with Windows Audio again? Most games use DirectX Sound and thus don't work properly, either.... It really sucks.

Comment: Go to Control Panel -> Sound -> Playback tab, right-click your device and choose Properties, then Enhancements tab. Verify that "Virtual Surround" (or "Speaker Fill") is checked, then click OK.

Comment: @harrymc the enhancement tab doesn't exist for this device...

Comment: Windos Update might have updated the driver. Try to roll the driver back in Device Manager ([link](https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-roll-back-a-driver-in-windows-2619217)).

Comment: i checked it, i can't do a rollback so it seems the driver wasn't updated

Comment: Try Control Panel > Troubleshooting > Troubleshoot audio playback.

Comment: it tells me to disable extensions, but when i go to "show extensions" it only shows a button to start the logitech gaming software.. it tells me to reboot, going to do that now

Comment: it worked! thank you so much! would you create an answer for this so I can accept it and award you the bounty?

Comment: Done as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 can get into trouble as regarding sound.

The following advice fixed the poster's problem, and mine as well when
I upgraded to Windows 10 and found that sound no longer worked:

Start the audio troubleshooter by :

```
Control Panel > Troubleshooting > Troubleshoot audio playback
```

Then choose your device and follow instructions,

[image: Control Panel]

[image: Troubleshoot audio playback]